# Elasticsearch get results where query is found within the n first words

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I would like to get results only if specific fields contains what i search within the 300 first words.

For example:

- The user query is "Covid-19"
- Elasticsearch should give him results where "Covid-19" is present in the 300 first words of the content of an article that I indexed.

I looked at span_query and specifically at span_first with his end parameter. It works pretty well but it looks like span_first is for one word only. For example if span_term is "Covid" i get some results but if span_term is "Covid 19" i don't get any results anymore. I would like to get the same result but with an entire expression e.g "Covid 19".

Is it possible?